# How does an inductor behave alone with a voltage source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor

I am trying to understand inductors, and [Kahn Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-natural-and-forced-response/a/wmc-inductor-in-action#:%7E:text=Now%20we%20have%20an%20inductor,of%20current%20through%20the%20inductor.) said that the current on the following circuit would be 300*t*, where *t* is time and initial time is 0.

[image: A 10 mH inductor connected directly to a 5 V voltage source]

There would be an increasing current, but both [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) and [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) disagree. Their simulations showed a constant current: CircuitLab showed a vertical spike then "*3e+15 A*", and LTspice showed "3 KA" constanly.

How should the circuit behave (voltages and currents)? Have I done the simulation wrong or is Khan Academy wrong? Or are we both wrong?

Update: as also suggested by ErnestoG, I changed the initial conditions to “external DC supply voltages at 0 V”. And presto! The formula is right!

Comment: When you run *time domain simulation* in **CircuitLab**, you may get different results depending on whether you check **skip initial** as **yes** or **no**.  If you check **no**, a faulty run (with no warning) results. Perhaps numerical overflow. If you check **yes**, current starts from zero at t=0.

Comment: The constant current reflects different assumptions. 3e15 (3,000,000,000,000,000 Amps) is probably numerical saturation. LT spice might be assuming a 1 mOhm series resistance either in L1 or in V1. Of course this is all fantasy land stuff. You can't have 3 peta Amps of current. You might have 3 kA, in a real circuit, but that is a lot of current. You need heavy solid busbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you might set things up in LTspice:

[image]

Note that I used the **UIC** keyword in the **.TRAN** card? This tells LTspice not to attempt a DC steady-state analysis first, but to "just run it."

I also needed to make sure that the default series resistance of the inductor was *nil*. To do that, I set it to \$1\:\mu\Omega\$. If I didn't do that, then LTspice would try and make some other "reasonable" assumption and use \$1\:\text{m}\Omega\$, instead. At \$300\:\text{A}\$ it would make a slight difference in the curve. So I cut it down by a factor of 1000 to minimize that problem. (It's still important to include a little bit of resistance so that Spice can treat it using a Norton equivalence.)

So, as with any software tool, there's a learning period where you need to get up to speed with some details about using it.

But the above shows just what you were told to expect. So all is right with the world.

Answer (score 1):

You should show how you're simulating your amplifier. But the quick answer is that you should simulate this with an pulsed signal, as it best mimics the step response of your amplifier.

You could also just use an option for starting up your voltage source at 0, and you'll most likely see the initial transient to be close to your 300t you get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ErnestoG. I did something similar, and it did work! Thank you! Do you believe I should delete this question? I ask because I don't know the Electronic SE community.

Comment: Your question is fine, just add more details about how you are executing your sims next time.

Answer (score 1):

Show the results of the LTSpice and circuitlab simulations.

The correct result for the exact circuit you've posted is 300t, which is infinite when t becomes infinite.

Simulators will often include extra stray components in their component models that they don't show you, to prevent infinities, for instance 1 mΩ in series with inductors. They may also run the simulation to a steady state before they 'start' if you don't tell it explicitly what the initial conditions are, so in this case you would get a steady current.

If you show the results, we might be able to figure out what the extra components are.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I updated the [question], and I do believe you are correct. [Edited by a moderator to clarify what was updated.]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much experience you have in calculus, but this is fundamentally the "...*plus a constant*" of integration.  (Which is a common enough phrase (or punchline) that you might've heard of it in this context, even if you haven't worked with it directly yet.)

The dynamic behavior of the system in question, is simply a ramp.  For a constant voltage, current rises linearly with time.  In the general case, current equals the integral of voltage.

For all time.  Positive or negative.

We can go forwards or backwards perfectly in time, and always have an answer -- or, a relative answer at least.  There is nothing special, anywhere along that line; it has no start, and no end.

Therein lies the trick: current is the integral of voltage *plus a constant*.  If we set that constant to zero, we get arguably the simplest case, a ramp that intercepts (0, 0) -- but there is nothing technically special about that coordinate.  If that happens to be the case we want to model, great; but the equations don't prioritize that case over any other one, and we can choose it however we like/need.

This is all that the simulators are telling you (although maybe to different degrees of accuracy).

You see, the more powerful simulator engines, like SPICE, try to help you out.  They try to solve the circuit at DC -- to give a starting point that's likely to settle faster than if everything were just set to zero.  This might even be required to get some quirky circuits operating at all!

But this doesn't work so well for a circuit like this, which in fact has a singular matrix.*  The simulator, still trying to help you out, may make certain assertions -- like setting internal resistance of the source or inductor (check the component properties!), or systematically as by GMIN and RSHUNT.

In general, any time you have any number of 1. voltage sources or inductors in parallel, or 2. current sources or capacitors in series, you have a singular matrix, which is to say, the current in the loop between those components (first case), or the voltage on the floating nodes (second case), is undefined -- a free variable, it could be anything.  But as a deterministic system, it must assign *something* to begin the calculation at all, and since it cannot, this error ("singular matrix") is [usually] emitted.  Again, there are hacks which may allow it to proceed regardless -- and this seems to have happened here.  Hence the absurdly high current -- which is perfectly reasonable given the approach described above, if we just hand-wave and say the resistance is not actually zero, but a few microohms.  And, like, who'll ever miss a few microohms, anyway? Right?!**

*This is linear algebra's equivalent of dividing by zero.  You can't just divide by a matrix, the way you can divide a regular number by a [nonzero] number; but you can take its inverse, and multiply by that.

What is a matrix doing here?  Simulators represent every node and branch in the circuit with an equation; those equations, tabulated together, form a matrix.  The solution to those simultaneous equations is given by a matrix inversion.  So, we use linear algebra to solve all those equations together, in an easily scalable way.

**Another valuable feature of a simulator is generality.  If you scale all variables by a factor of a billion, does it still give essentially the same results (scaled appropriately)?  The arithmetic is identical; it certainly should.  (Under the hood, simulators use floating point numbers, which are well-behaved with respect to scaling, so that shouldn't be a problem.)

It may seem straightforward and effective for a simulator to automatically add series resistors of some microohms everywhere, or shunt resistors of gigohms.  But these un-scaled hacks will not work for every circuit, so they need to be kept in mind.  (This is, more or less, why SPICE gives you a range of parameters you can set -- ABSTOL, CHGTOL, VNTOL, RSHUNT, GMIN, etc.  There are many scale-dependent hacks used by SPICE, actually, and these give you some control over, basically, what range of values the simulator should expect to operate on.)

---

It's probably illustrative to note at this point, too: the simulator doesn't know anything about what components you are putting down (or that you think you might be putting down).  It's certainly not advanced enough to understand intent, and it doesn't know anything more about reality than the models fed into it.  It's perfectly possible, indeed easy, to make an utterly nonphysical circuit: it is entirely your responsibility, as the user of this tool -- it's just a tool, like any other, after all -- to ensure that the system, and the models used to build it, are representative of some real circuit you're looking to recreate.

This may even seem obvious, at times (you can't buy an arbitrary dependent source off the shelf!), but I think the fact that simulators provide models named for real components, can lend a false sense of security for the results.  As in all things -- one must be careful, checking those assumptions early and often!

Which, on that note -- if you tried to reverse-simulate this circuit by building it in real life, you'd find you cannot get an ideal voltage source nor an ideal inductor, at all.  The closet you will get, will just roll over and flatten out at some number of amperes -- it's actually an RL network, resistance is unavoidable.  (Or maybe quench and explode, if you try it with a superconductor!  In any case, something other than an infinite ramp will happen.)  But, you would also find that, if you confine your measurements to just a small range of times, a ramp is observed; namely for time periods much less than the L/R time constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$V = L\cdot \dfrac{di}{dt}$$

Or...

$$\dfrac{di}{dt} = \dfrac{V}{L}$$

This means that if you suddenly apply 3 volts across a 10 mH inductor (and ideal inductor), the current ramps up at 300 amps per second.

> *Their simulations showed a constant current*

Because most simulations initially calculate the DC conditions; you want to prevent this from happening to get the truer picture.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is right. The current will increase endlessly with an ideal voltage source and an ideal inductor. You won't find either. Now think about what the simulation program should do to simulate that condition. Should you provide a useless result where the current increases beyond the rating of realizeable conductors and components, or do you make the voltage source and inductor imperfect with some series resistance? There's no definitive standard for imperfection. CircuitLab and LTSpice came up with their own answers.